# Error in adding TargetData in PassManager in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am beginner to llvm. I am implementing a program main.cpp of https://github.com/davidar/lljvm/blob/master/backend/main.cpp . When I am declaring a `PassManager PM
 PM.add(new DataLayout td)`,  it throws a error :

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘PM’
  PassManager PM;
```

As keeping above error in mind I change the command as

```
PassManger<Module> PM
PM.add(new DataLayout td)
```

Now, there is different error : `error: ‘class llvm::PassManager<llvm::Module>’ has no member named ‘add’` I dont know whether the above changes is correct way or not?
 Here is a source code:

```
#include "backened.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeReader.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ErrorOr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/PassManager.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/Passes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DataLayout.h"
#include <llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h>
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"

using namespace llvm;
using namespace std;    
static cl::opt<string> input(cl::Positional, cl::desc("Bitcode File.."),cl::Required);
static cl::opt<string> classname("classname",cl::desc("Binary name of the generated class..."));    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "LLVM Bitcode ..");
        LLVMContext context; 

        ErrorOr<unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>>  mb = MemoryBuffer::getFile(input);
        if(error_code ec = mb.getError())
        {
                errs() << ec.message();
                return 1;
        }    
        Expected<unique_ptr<Module>> m = parseBitcodeFile(mb->get()->getMemBufferRef(),context);
        if(error_code ec= errorToErrorCode(m.takeError()) )
        {

        PassManager<Module> PM;
        DataLayout td("e-p:32:32:32"
                 "-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64"
                 "-f32:32:32-f64:64:64");
        PM.add(new DataLayout(td));
         return 0;
}
```

Also, suggest me whether I have implemented a correct way the `DataLayout td`  inplace of `TargetData td` as  I found TargetData.h is removed from newer version of llvm.

Answer (score 1):

The PassManager used in that example has moved into the legacy namespace,

so use `#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"`

Change the variable declaration to `legacy::PassManager PM;`